# Random IO typing in haskell

Tags: haskell, ghci

I want the function to draw a number, and if it is greater than 7, send an approval message and call this add function.

However, my function only falls on the 'else'. The "disapproved" message appears. I think it's the IO Float typing with Float. How can I solve this?

```
mySort:: Float -> Int
mySort = ceiling(10 * x)


numberSort:: IO ()
numberSort = do    
    num <- randomIO :: IO Float
    print $ mySort num
    if(num >= 7) then
        do
            putStrLn ("approved!" ++ "\n") >> add
        else
        do
            putStrLn "disapproved!"
```

Comment: `randomIO :: IO Float` will produce a float between 0 and 1, so what you probably mean to do here is compare `num` with `0.7` rather than `7`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`randomIO` works like [`random`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html#v:random), which uses `[0,1)` for fractional types.

> ```
> random :: RandomGen g => g -> (a, g)
> ```
>
> The same as `randomR`, but using a default range determined by the type:
>
> - For bounded types (instances of Bounded, such as Char), the range is normally the whole type.
> - ***For fractional types, the range is normally the semi-closed interval [0,1).*** [emphasis mine]
> - For Integer, the range is (arbitrarily) the range of `Int`.

Use [`randomRIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html#v:randomRIO) instead, e.g.

```
num <- randomRIO (0, 10) :: IO Float
```